# How to connect another database with model in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database-connection

I am able to connect with another database like this

```
DB::connection('connection_2')->table("users")->get();
```

But this code is not working

```
User::connection('connection_2')->get();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `$connection` property of your model like so:

```
class MyModel extends Eloquent {
    protected $connection = 'connection_2';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add in database.php:

```
'main' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database' => env('DB_MAIN', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false
],
'admin' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database' => env('DB_ADMIN', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false
]
```

Then use:

```
DB::connection('main')->table("users")->get();
DB::connection('admin')->table("users")->get();
```

In your `User.php` model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'main';
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = [
       'id','name'
    ];
}
```

Then use:

```
User::get();
```

Comment: I am able to connect with another database like this

Comment: in you model you can add                                                                               `protected $connection = 'main';
    protected $table = 'users';`

Comment: In you user model use protected $connection = 'main';